Predator PH315-54 and GPU fan control issue on Linux
When the GPU fan kicks in, it sometimes gets stuck at high speed even when the system is idle. This happens randomly, and I have to reboot to get it back to normal. I have dual boot installed with GRUB, running Linux and previously Windows, but I have now uninstalled Windows.
Here are my specs:
Model: Acer Predator PH315-54
BIOS Version: V1.11 (no BIOS upgrade has been done)
GPU: NVIDIA (with driver version 550 proprietary)
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (formerly dual-boot with Windows)
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-45-generic

I've noticed this issue especially after switching to the newer NVIDIA driver on Linux (previously v535) . I'm wondering if it's related to the driver, BIOS, or some interaction between the system BIOS and the fan control. Is there a way to control or reset the fan speed directly from Linux, or is there another fix for this issue?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

It's my very last Acer.. zero support for Linux
